# dylib set by rpath is not loaded in OS X

Tags: macos, package-managers, dyld

I am making a package manager, and would like to ensure the packages use the correct dependent library by setting `rpath` option at compile time. But it surprised me in OS X (10.11), here is the problem:

```
$ otool -L /opt/starman/software/gcc/6.1.0/83894f21d07366be296600ec031ae4f6241381d9/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.5.0/6.1.0/f951 
/opt/starman/software/gcc/6.1.0/83894f21d07366be296600ec031ae4f6241381d9/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.5.0/6.1.0/f951:
    /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.0.0)
    /opt/starman/software/isl/0.17.1/104994def2b7fb2dae7950b42205eb718a46ee0c/lib/libisl.15.dylib (compatibility version 18.0.0, current version 18.1.0)
    /opt/starman/software/mpc/1.0.3/6058925218009b8ab17e07333dc54de334134f6e/lib/libmpc.3.dylib (compatibility version 4.0.0, current version 4.0.0)
    /opt/starman/software/mpfr/3.1.4/f142dfcda3b56650a8c9cfe2fdd09ffdf7283a00/lib/libmpfr.4.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.4.0)
    /opt/starman/software/gmp/6.1.0/0ec8ef118d09cb33f83559685d006f56a74f865c/lib/libgmp.10.dylib (compatibility version 14.0.0, current version 14.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1226.10.1)
```

see `gmp` version is `14.0.0`.

```
$ /opt/starman/software/gcc/6.1.0/83894f21d07366be296600ec031ae4f6241381d9/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.5.0/6.1.0/f951 
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/starman/software/gmp/6.1.0/0ec8ef118d09cb33f83559685d006f56a74f865c/lib/libgmp.10.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/starman/software/gcc/6.1.0/83894f21d07366be296600ec031ae4f6241381d9/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.5.0/6.1.0/f951
  Reason: Incompatible library version: f951 requires version 14.0.0 or later, but libgmp.10.dylib provides version 13.0.0
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

It says `gmp` in the correct path is not loaded since its version is `13.0.0`, but it is `14.0.0`! I know I have an older version `gmp` installed in another path, so after I remove its lib path from `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, the problem is gone, but shouldn't `rpath` solve this problem?

Why `dyld` prints the correct path of `gmp`, but actually uses the wrong old? Is there any tricks in OS X? Thanks for help!

**EDIT 1**:
The version of `/opt/starman/software/gmp/6.1.0/0ec8ef118d09cb33f83559685d006f56a74f865c/lib/libgmp.10.dylib` is checked as

```
$ otool -l /opt/starman/software/gmp/6.1.0/0ec8ef118d09cb33f83559685d006f56a74f865c/lib/libgmp.10.dylib
...
      cmdsize 120
         name /opt/starman/software/gmp/6.1.0/0ec8ef118d09cb33f83559685d006f56a74f865c/lib/libgmp.10.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 1 Thu Jan  1 08:00:01 1970
      current version 14.0.0
compatibility version 14.0.0
...
```

And the older `gmp` is

```
$ otool -l /opt/software/gmp/6.0.0a/0/lib/libgmp.10.dylib
...
         name @rpath/lib/libgmp.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 1 Thu Jan  1 08:00:01 1970
      current version 13.0.0
compatibility version 13.0.0
...
```

**EIDT 2**

According to `0xced`, I run debug the loading process as (**The full output is [here](https://gist.github.com/dongli/c0b8153573db0332ef519c74341cd264)**):

```
$ export DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES="1"
$ /opt/starman/software/gcc/6.1.0/83894f21d07366be296600ec031ae4f6241381d9/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.5.0/6.1.0/f951
dyld: loaded: /opt/starman/software/gcc/6.1.0/83894f21d07366be296600ec031ae4f6241381d9/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.5.0/6.1.0/f951
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
dyld: loaded: /opt/starman/software/isl/0.17.1/104994def2b7fb2dae7950b42205eb718a46ee0c/lib/libisl.15.dylib
dyld: loaded: /opt/software/packman.active/lib/libmpc.3.dylib
dyld: loaded: /opt/software/packman.active/lib/libmpfr.4.dylib
dyld: loaded: /opt/software/packman.active/lib/libgmp.10.dylib
dyld: unloaded: /opt/starman/software/gcc/6.1.0/83894f21d07366be296600ec031ae4f6241381d9/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.5.0/6.1.0/f951
dyld: unloaded: /opt/starman/software/isl/0.17.1/104994def2b7fb2dae7950b42205eb718a46ee0c/lib/libisl.15.dylib
dyld: unloaded: /opt/software/packman.active/lib/libmpc.3.dylib
dyld: unloaded: /opt/software/packman.active/lib/libmpfr.4.dylib
dyld: unloaded: /opt/software/packman.active/lib/libgmp.10.dylib
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/starman/software/gmp/6.1.0/0ec8ef118d09cb33f83559685d006f56a74f865c/lib/libgmp.10.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/starman/software/gcc/6.1.0/83894f21d07366be296600ec031ae4f6241381d9/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.5.0/6.1.0/f951
  Reason: Incompatible library version: f951 requires version 14.0.0 or later, but libgmp.10.dylib provides version 13.0.0
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Comment: What's rpath got to do with the question?  Are you sure that version of the `gmp` library is 14 and not 13?

Comment: Because the `gmp` library path is hardcoded in `f951`, and I think this is the effect of `rpath`. The versions of the two `gmp` on my computer are shown above by using `otool -l`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why the `f951` binary would load `/opt/software/gmp/6.0.0a/0/lib/libgmp.10.dylib` (version 13) rather than `/opt/starman/software/gmp/6.1.0/0ec8ef118d09cb33f83559685d006f56a74f865c/lib/libgmp.10.dylib` (version 14) which is specified with an absolute path and not a relative `@rpath`.

Maybe it’s loaded indirectly via another library, e.g. libisl.15.dylib, libmpc.3.dylib or libmpfr.4.dylib which could have an @rpath reference to libgmp.10.dylib?

To diagnose this issue, I suggest you to run the main executable like this:

```
$ DYLD_PRINT_RPATHS=YES /opt/starman/software/gcc/6.1.0/83894f21d07366be296600ec031ae4f6241381d9/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.5.0/6.1.0/f951
```

This will print all rpath expansions (both failure and success) and will probably give you the answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks for help! I checked those dylibs, and they all loaded the correct `gmp`. I also run `f951` with `DYLD_PRINT_RPATHS=YES`, but it does not print more information.

Comment: I export `DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES` to 1 referring `https://gist.github.com/wycats/1627976`, and it printed. The full output is [here](https://gist.github.com/dongli/c0b8153573db0332ef519c74341cd264)

Comment: Does it work if you remove `/opt/software/packman.active/lib` from your `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable?

Comment: Can you please try the **exact command** in my answer, i.e. `DYLD_PRINT_RPATHS=YES /opt/starman/software/gcc/6.1.0/83894f21d07366be296600ec031ae4f6241381d9/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.5.0/6.1.0/f951` ? You should get rpath debug logs.

Comment: I have tried exactly as your command, and it printed no debug logs.

Comment: Does it work if you try to print rpath debug logs on another executable, for example, Xcode? `DYLD_PRINT_RPATHS=YES /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode`

Comment: If `libgmp.10.dylib` is loaded from `/opt/software/packman.active/lib` then it probably means that one of your dylib is referencing it without an absolute path. And since `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` contains `/opt/software/packman.active/lib` it's loaded from there. You should check all your dylibs with `otool -L` to see if there's a dependency without an absolute path.